# Travel from Dallas to Toronto

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports

I'm a US citizen and I wish to travel from Dallas to Toronto to Boston. 
I assume that I'll need my passport for this trip – Is this correct?
And how much time (roughly) will it take to go through immigration and customs in Toronto and Boston?

Comment: You don't necessarily need a passport. An enhanced drivers license EDL may work depending on your circumstances. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_Drivers_License You should not take more than half an hour going through immigration and customs.

Comment: @SheikPaul thx. I have the passport and no EDL. So I'll use the passport which I assume they will stamp?

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: @DavidRicherby My citizenship is US.

Comment: They may or may not stamp the passport. They keep electronic records of entries which makes the stamp kind of optional for most visitors, and particularly so for Americans who can enter with non-passport documents that can't be stamped. Whether they bother with the stamp in a passport seems to depend on the mood of the officer you see. If you use the ABC machines (Americans can do so) the officer you see after probably won't have a stamp.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thank you for editing my question. You did a wonderful job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toronto Pearson has a website where you can fill in your flight details, and it will tell you if you need to cross immigration or not. https://www.torontopearson.com/Connecting.aspx

If it shows you have to cross immigration you will need a passport, otherwise not. In case you travel without a passport, you should be prepared to explain your connection at the gate in Dallas.

Comment: For the record, you will clear customs and immigration in Toronto both times, once arriving (Canada Customs), and once departing (US Customs preclearance).  One arrives from Pearson airport into Boston (or anywhere in the US) as a domestic passenger.